# TI-89 Reduce Row Echelon Form Output Display

Tags: matrix, calculator, display

Is there are way to display/scroll through a matrix that is bigger than 3x3. When I use the rref() function, the output only display the first three rows.

I can select that solution and look through the whole matrix via the command line (from the picture, last row is

```
[0 0 1 256/27 0]
```

but is the a more effective way to view the solution. Say I have a 10x10 matrix solution. Are there any alternative options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the matrix to a variable, there is a Matrix Editor application under the APPS button. You can open the matrix variable from there.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks!